# Diverting gpu output via c/c++ libraries

Tags: video, io, gpu

Problem:  I'm looking for a way to divert the output of the gpu, say an Nvidia Geforce, through the bus to other components.  For starters, a simple text file with the raw data will do.  I dont need to leverage the processing power of the gpu in anyway, I just want the raw output that would be sent to the monitor and so I doubt Cuda is a viable solution. "Print Screen" screen comes to mind.  Theres also various programs that capture output and store it in a video file.  This almost works, but I'm more interested in the data structure of raw hdmi, serial, or digital output(whatever the cords are called) ie the blue, white, or hdmi cords. I'm willing to use either linux or windows to accomplish this task. Sample code would be nice, but more importantly a gentle push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing (a) the contents of the frame buffer, (b) the video content, and (c) the physical bus signals are three completely different requests.

If you want (a) then search for screen capture tools and libraries.
If you want (b) then search for screen recording tools or consider using a video capture card and route your output into the video card.
If you want (c) then search for HDMI, DVI, VGA bus analyzer and be prepared to pay significant money.  http://www.home.agilent.com/agilent/product.jspx?cc=AW&lc=eng&ckey=1143984&nid=-536902932.687229.00&id=1143984.